# Move an LXC container to a dm-crypt/LUKS filesystem

Tags: upstart, lxc, disk-encryption, luks

I need to move a container to a different filesystem, specifically a subdir of an already mounted LUKS/dm-crypt home dir.  I tried moving it there and then bind mounting or symlinking it to /var/lib/lxc/foo but when I do `lxc-start -n foo` just exits immediately.

Debugging output just says `lxc_start - container init process exited` and `lxc_error - child <30146> ended on error (1)`.  I get no output from upstart even with `lxc-start -n foo /sbin/init --verbose` so it looks like `/sbin/init` is exiting before it does anything.  I get the same if if I symlink the whole `/var/lib/lxc` dir into the dm-crypt home and do a lxc-create for a totally fresh container but it works just fine if the container is symlinked from the same filesystem.

How can I move the container to the dm-crypt home dir such that it will run?

This is on Ubuntu 12.10 using `sudo lxc-create -n foo -t ubuntu`.

Comment: Why not just _mount_ the encrypted filesystem there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want a *subdir* of the *already mounted* home dir to be the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the mount options used.  Because I was using pam_mount and some copying and pasting I had the `nodev` and `nosuid` options on.  Once I took those out, it worked.